# IPC FIFO Producer-Consumer Deadlock

Tags: c, linux, process, posix, ipc

This is the producer.

```
// speak.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define FIFO_NAME "american_maid"

int main(void)
{
    char s[300];
    int num, fd;

    mknod(FIFO_NAME, S_IFIFO | 0666, 0);

    printf("waiting for readers...\n");
    fd = open(FIFO_NAME, O_WRONLY);
    printf("got a reader--type some stuff\n");

    while (gets(s), !feof(stdin)) {
        if ((num = write(fd, s, strlen(s))) == -1)
            perror("write");
        else
            printf("speak: wrote %d bytes\n", num);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And this is the consumer.

```
//tick.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define FIFO_NAME "american_maid"

int main(void)
{
    char s[300];
    int num, fd;

    mknod(FIFO_NAME, S_IFIFO | 0666, 0);

    printf("waiting for writers...\n");
    fd = open(FIFO_NAME, O_RDONLY);
    printf("got a writer\n");

    do {
        if ((num = read(fd, s, 300)) == -1)
            perror("read");
        else {
            s[num] = '\0';
            printf("tick: read %d bytes: \"%s\"\n", num, s);
        }
    } while (num > 0);

    return 0;
}
```

When I run them, Producer outputs,

```
waiting for readers...
```

And consumer outputs,

```
waiting for writers...
```

*speak* doesn't find the reader, *tick*. As from the [theory here](http://beej.us/guide/bgipc/output/html/multipage/fifos.html#fifopc) I got that, **open()** (speak.c) will be keep blocked until **open()** (tick.c) is opened. And the vice versa. So I guess there a deadlock or something happening. I need a solution of this.

Comment: It works perfectly for me. Did you type something in?

Comment: Just to be sure: you are starting the two processes in the same directory, right? (mknod in both places looks a bit strange)

Comment: @Dacav Yes. I typed but nothing happened. How did you run them? And, Mat Yes. they'r on the same dir.

Comment: `while (gets(s), !feof(stdin)) {...}` is wrong. Should *at least* be `while (gets(s) && !feof(stdin)) {...}` , which is still ugly (and wrong).

Comment: `gets()` is eeevil ... ;-) - consider using `fgets()`

Comment: @wildplasser: technically speaking the syntax is valid. Probably not that clear but valid.

Comment: I know the syntax, I know the komma operator. Semantically, it is plain wrong, because it would cause the program to loop/hang if another error condition (other than EOF) would have caused the bad read. Also, consulting feof() after every I/O operation is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a race condition between the reader and the writer.

To fix this, you need a method of not launching the reader until the writer is "active". For this, I'd suggest making a pipe and writing to it when the writer is ready. Then, when reading from the read end of the fork succeeds, the fifo is prepared and the reader should work.

You need to use forks here because coordinating mutexes between a parent and a child process is non-trivial and properly done pipes is easier.

Also, you called `mknod()` twice. Granted, it'll return -1 with `errno == EEXIST`, but be more careful. To avoid this, make the reader and writer a function that takes a path as an argument.

Rewrite your writer as `int speak(const char *fifo, int pipefd)` and your reader as `int tick(const char *fifo)`.

Then make a wrapper like this:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

const char fifo_name[] /* = ... */;

int speak(const char *fifo, int pipefd);
int tick(const char *fifo);

int main() {
    int pipefd[2];
    pipe(pipefd);

    mknod(fifo_name, S_IFIFO | 0666, 0);

    if (fork() == 0) {
        close(pipefd[0]);
        return speak(fifo_name, pipefd[1]);
    } else {
        close(pipefd[1]);
        char foo;
        read(pipefd[0], &foo, 1);
        return tick(fifo_name);
    }
}
```

Modify your writer to print a byte (of anything) to the passed fd after the fifo is created (i.e. right after the call to `open(..., O_WRONLY)`).

Don't use my code verbatim, as I've omitted error checking for the sake of brevity.

Answer (score 0):

it runs ok in my env. and if reader and writer is ready, open will return.  because open is blocked, so in my opinion, mknod function is success. May be you excute these two process at different path.